# Angular 2 issues with boolean comparison in a directive

Tags: angular, directive, ngfor

I'm new to Angular 2 and I have no idea why my directive isn't working.

Here is my directive:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[j-slider]',
})
export class JSliderDirective {
 elRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.elRef = elRef;
  }

  @Input('j-slider') last: boolean;

 ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.last);
   if (this.last == true)
     console.log('pass');
  }

}
```

my  HTML:

```
<div class="shopping-slider">
    <div class="shopping-slide" *ngFor='let product of products; let last = last' j-slider="{{last ? true: false}}">
        <img src="{{product.img}}" alt="{{product.name}}"/>
        <p class="shopping-label">{{product.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want my init statement to run after the repeat has finished. When I log 'this.last' before the if statement, it gives me false and then true for the final repeat, which is correct. However, my if statement is failing... why? What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself a huge favor and use the Angular 2 `[bind]` syntax!

Right now using the curly braces `{{}}` is implicitly passing `true` and `false` as strings, and `"true" != true`. Not good.

Simply wrap the `j-slider` attribute like so:

```
<div class="shopping-slide" *ngFor='let product of products; let last = last' [j-slider]="last">
```

and viola!